# Clear All ShelockFragmentActvity from Stack

Tags: android, android-activity, actionbarsherlock

I have a small doubt about the Clear all Activity on Top of Stack. But In every class of activity, I am not extending the `Activity`, in-place of activity I extends `SherlockFragmentActivity`.

ex:

```
class A extends SherlockFragmentActivity. 
                  or

class A extends SherlockActivity
```

So like that I have ten classes. I want to Logout of the screen then need to show only the Login screen and remaining all should be finish. So for I called like that.

```
Intent intent=new Intent(A.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

But it is not finishing all Activity from stack and again back press it showing the remaining all Activity in stack.

Please help me Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just to complement your question, I'm using the same code as you, and it's clearing all SherlockActivity and FragmentActivity from the stack, maybe it's something about the SherlockFragmentActivity...

Comment: It not working with SherlockActivity also.